# Use of backwards facing diode next to motor

Tags: voltage, transistors, diodes, npn

While tyring to figure out how to best control a 12V device from a raspberry pi or arduino I ran into the following image:
[image]

Now I'm wondering, what is D1 doing there? What's the use of that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the transistor switches open, energy stored in the motor can cause a back emf and destroy the transistor so the diode provides a current path for that energy to prevent this happening.

The same applies to switching any magnetic component such as a relay, a solenoid or a transformer.